# Requiring a library in the attributes of a Chef cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, require, cookbook

In my chef cookbook's `attributes/default.rb` I have the following:

```
default['dt'] = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('America/Chicago').local_to_utc(Time.now)
```

In my `recipe/default.rb` I have

```
chef_gem 'active_support/time'
```

Which if I understood correctly, would work same as a

```
gem install 'active_support/time'
require 'active_support/time'
```

But upon running the cookbook I get

```
NameError
---------
uninitialized constant Class::TZInfo
```

How do I resolve the NameError?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There is no question.

Answer (score 0):

all attribute files are evaluated prior to any recipe files being evaluated.  Therefore, when your recipe code runs, the gem has not yet been installed.  Even if it had been, it would not be included in your attributes file, and therefore would not be available there.  As for how to fix it, that's a tough one.  I'd suggest you move the attribute setting code out of the attributes file and into the recipe.  Generally I frown on that, but sometimes it is unavoidable.